# Is it possible to have navigation property on a class that isn't in the context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

for example if I have `Entity` Model

```
public class Creature
{
    [Key]
    public int CreatureID { get; set; }
    public int Weakness { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

then I register it in the `Context`

```
public class RPGContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Creature> Creature { get; set; }
    ...
```

let's say I create a new `class` that isn't in the `Context`

```
public class Troll
{
    public int TrollID { get; set; }
    public int CreatureID { get; set; }

    public virtual Creature Creature { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to have navigation property to `Creature` on `Troll` class? Means that if I set `CreatureID` to certain value, the navigation property will automatically filled.

Sorry for silly question, I'm new to `EF`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How would that work? for EF this simply does not exist. of course you can add the navigation property, but it won't do anything until you fill the value.

Comment: simple answer, No, but ofcourse you can add a property in a non EF class that has a key value to a EF entity...